# http-basic-auth against webserver with vbs

Tags: powershell, vbscript, basic-authentication

i need to connect to a webserver using vbscript. Using powershell this works flawless:

```
$url = "https://someserver:9200/?q=name:Hans"

$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic c29tZXVzZXI6c29tZXBhc3M=" }

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Headers $headers
```

Now i need to do the same with vbscript:

```
url = "https://someserver:9200/?q=name:Hans"

Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
xmlHttp.Open "POST", url, false
xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic c29tZXVzZXI6c29tZXBhc3M="
xmlHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlHttp.send
```

Sadly this gives me an error:

```
A certificate is required to complete client authentication
```

What am I doing wrong?

beMoD

Answer (score 0):

It works in PowerShell because the [WebRequest] object sets a bunch of default parameters and it looks like WinHTTPRequest COM (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383998(v=vs.85).aspx) object does not.  In order to manually set those properties, you need to use the .Option property on the WinHTTPRequest object to set indexes with values that match the required WinHTTPRequest Enumeration:  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384108(v=vs.85).aspx).  E.g.:

```
xmlHttp.Option(0) = "http_requester/0.1"
xmlHttp.Option(4) = 13056
xmlHttp.Option(6) = "True"
xmlhttp.Option(12) = "True"
```